# Can't Complete Code over File error how do i fix

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I can't seem to figure out what is going on here.
I have posted below my code and a photo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;


namespace test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddExtensions(new File("pathtoextentions.crx"));

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            //Test Opening Website

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

I have also uploaded a photo here where it show my error is on new File: https://ibb.co/Lk72dsD

> Error CS0712  Cannot create an instance of the static class 'File'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the top bar, go to view>error list, copy the actual error message and put it in your question. The image you have sent only shows where the error is, not what the error is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-7.0) is a static class, you can't create instances of it like `new File()`.

Looking at [`ChormeOptions.AddExtensions`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/Overload_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions_AddExtensions.htm), it accepts an array or an IEnumerable of string.

So, we could use an array in your case. To do so, replace this:

```
options.AddExtensions(new File("pathtoextentions.crx"));
```

with this:

```
options.AddExtensions(new[] { "pathtoextentions.crx" });
```